# Atom - search by extension in selected folder

Tags: atom-editor

When I search for certain string ("Search in directory"), atom allows to do 2 things: specify directory or file extension (but then it searches in all directories in project). Is it possible to do both at the same time? E.g. I want to do recursive search in 'src' directory, but using only *.c and *.cpp files.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try searching using `src/**/*.c` as file/directory pattern.

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't work on Windows https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/744

Comment: On Mac with remote connection to linux server, it just hangs. But if i just do src/, results come back instantaneously. I just wish there is an easy way to filter by file extension afterwards.

Comment: In fact on Mac with remote connection to linux server, I can't even put a single file path in the File/directory pattern field. The only thing that works is either a single directory path or multiple directories possibly with negation, separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

To search both `*.c` and `*.cpp` files, use `,`:

`src/**/*.c, src/**/*.cpp`

To speed things up, use `!` to exclude an unwanted directory:

`src/**/*.c, src/**/*.cpp, !src/not_this_dir/`